# How do I create a new server in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

The questions is basically the title because I could not find any articles to help as they only help on how to create a new database however I cant seem to create/join my own server.

The first picture attached is what I've seen other people do in order to get in however, I get an error when i try to connect

[image: What is advised to do]

[image: Error]

Comment: You are trying to connect to a server, you need to install it on the machine instead. SSMS does not include the SQL Server installation files, it's just a client to query the server. However there are downloads that include SQL Server with SSMS, so check what you have actually gotten.

Comment: You must install SQL SERVER Database Engine.

Answer (score 6):

SQL Server and SSMS are two seperate softwares. SQL Server creates a database engine on your machine and SSMS is used to visualize or perform operations on these Database Servers. You Need to install both SQL Server and SSMS. While you seem to have install only SSMS.

You Can Install SQL Server from this link
[SQL Server Download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads)

You can follow this link to [SQL Server Installation Tutorial](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/install-sql-server/)